# Getting Windows 10 Tablet to run a Wamp Server

Tags: php, windows, apache, wamp, jailbreak

I have a very basic Asus tablet (VivoTab) I just upgraded to Windows 10. I want to run an offline demo on it of my website, so my thought process is to install WAMP server and go from there. I've done it on my PC, but as you can imagine its a little different with a Tablet, and I can't seem to find much online information on the topic.

If there is a 'better' way to go about this, not using WAMP, or if someone has done this there help would be much appreciated!!

Preferably I don't want to jailbreak, but if its necessary I don't mind.

Comment: what the actual heck are you talking about? you want to run your tablet on your server? wtf does that even mean?

Comment: Why don't you go ahead with WAMP?Wamp for windows works on windows!!..So if it's available,then why don't you use it?Wamp wouldn't be affected by the display size or resolution.So what makes a tab so different than a PC in this case?

Comment: it doesn't matter if it is on desktop or tablet, as long as you are on full windows software that can run windows desktop program. it works the same. for light weight staging, try xampplite.

Comment: @Pamblam...He is talking about hosting a website on the localhost.Basically,converting the tablet to a website host(webserver).(using tools like WAMP and XAMPP).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone! After playing with some configs with wamp it worked. Had to uninstall it couple times, The tablet didn't play nicely with 3.0 but worked with 2.5. The difficulty was installing the correct MSVCR. For 2.5 Apache runs on MSVCR 2010 for 32bit but for some reason you need 2008 revision installed as well. Also had to block IIS it runs on port 80 as wel